# How extract string from escape character '\' using python regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have a text like below:

```
\Insights\Measures - Trending\01) POS\TARG Sales $\TARG Circular Sales $\TARG Circular Sales $
```

I would like to extract it from the last `'\'` character.

```
\Insights\Measures - Trending\01) POS\TARG Sales $\TARG Circular Sales $
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Do you want to remove `TARG Circular Sales $` from first string

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a regex for this, you just need [`str.rindex`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.rindex):

```
text = text[:text.rindex('\\')]
```

If you realle want to use a regex then you can use `re.sub`, use `$` to match the end of string and `[^\\]` to match everything that is not `\`:

```
import re

text = re.sub(r'\\[^\\]*$', '', text)
```

There are other N ways to match the same thing, but I believe it's an overkill in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s = '\Insights\Measures - Trending\01) POS\TARG Sales $\TARG Circular Sales $\TARG Circular Sales $'
>>> print (s.rsplit('\\', 1)[0])
\Insights\Measures - Trending) POS\TARG Sales $\TARG Circular Sales $
```

Answer (score 0):

With regex the solution is

```
new_text = re.search(r'(.*)\\', text).group(1)
```

But I do agree that regex is unnecessary in your example

Answer (score 0):

`string.split` will work here

```
a ="\Insights\Measures - Trending\01) POS\TARG Sales $\TARG Circular Sales $\TARG Circular Sales $"
print (a.split("\\")[-1])
```

Comment: Using `a.rsplit("\\", 1)` would probably be faster, especially as the number of potential splits increases.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for that. String methods do that easily:

```
>>> s='Insights\\Measures - Trending\\01) POS\\TARG Sales $\\TARG Circular Sales $\\TARG Circular Sales $'
>>> s
'Insights\\Measures - Trending\\01) POS\\TARG Sales $\\TARG Circular Sales $\\TARG Circular Sales $'
>>> s[:s.rindex('\\')]
'Insights\\Measures - Trending\\01) POS\\TARG Sales $\\TARG Circular Sales $'
>>>
```

Another easy way is:

```
>>> s.rpartition('\\')[0]
'Insights\\Measures - Trending\\01) POS\\TARG Sales $\\TARG Circular Sales $'
>>>
```